# I can assign external links to some different ids (modal) in my page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, modal-dialog

I can't write a unique javascript that can assign ids to be accessed and displayed by direct links.
On the page I have this gallery of images and captions:

```html
  <div class="modal-item">
        <a onclick="document.getElementById('id001').style.display='block'" class="item-link">
          <img class="thumb" src="image001"/>
      </div>
        <div id="id001" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                            <img alt="" src="image001big"/>
                        </div>
                     <caption></caption>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
  <div class="modal-item">
        <a onclick="document.getElementById('id002').style.display='block'" class="item-link">
          <img class="thumb" src="image001"/>
      </div>
        <div id="id002" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                            <img alt="" src="image002big"/>
                        </div>
                     <caption></caption>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
...
```

But after all my research I only got as far as this and it doesn't work. Also I shouldn't need to despecify the id every time otherwise I fill the page with scripts.

```js
 <script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {

  if(window.location.href.indexOf('#id0743') != -1) {
    $('#id0743').modal('show');document.getElementById('id0743').style.display='block';
  }

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier way to do this.  The window already has a built-in object called `window.location.hash`, which will return `#id001` if you go to `https://example.net/#id001`  Here is [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/hash) about it.

#### Location: hash

> The hash property of the Location interface returns a USVString
> containing a '#' followed by the fragment identifier of the URL — the
> ID on the page that the URL is trying to target.
>
> The fragment is not percent-decoded. If the URL does not have a
> fragment identifier, this property contains an empty string, "".

---

#### Here is a working version

Note that I'm manually assigning the ID, but that is alone because I can't get the actual hash from the `window`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    let id = window.location.hash;
  id = "#id002";
  
  $(id).css('display', 'block');
});

// Pure JS example
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  let id = window.location.hash.substring(1);
  id = "id001"
  document.getElementById(id).style.display='block';
});
```

```css
.modal {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-item">
  <a onclick="document.getElementById('id001').style.display='block'" class="item-link">
    <img class="thumb" src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/200" />
  </a>
</div>

<div id="id001" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <img alt="" src="https://www.fillmurray.com/2000/2000" />
  </div>
  <caption></caption>
</div>


<div class="modal-item">
  <a onclick="document.getElementById('id002').style.display='block'" class="item-link">
    <img class="thumb" src="https://www.fillmurray.com/199/199" />
  </a>
</div>

<div id="id002" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <img alt="" src="https://www.fillmurray.com/1999/1999" />
  </div>
  <caption></caption>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. The problem is that this way I have to rewrite the same script for all the ids in the page.

Comment: With this solution the id pops up every time you open the page. Instead it should only open when I add the specific id to the link.
miolink.html#id001

Comment: Remove the line `id = "id001"`, that way ID is equal to what ever your hash is.  In the example `miolink.html#id001` `window.location.hash` should equal `#id001`  in the example `miolink.html#id002` `window.location.hash` should equal `#id002`  and so forth

Comment: Yeaaa! Thank you so much♥

Comment: @NicolettaNigro, if you could accept the answer as being correct that would be great :)